# Creating Users With Parse and specifically for swift and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform

How would I create custom fields to add to the PFUser class in parse or is there anyway to create it from the beginning with the PFObject class? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS 
It explains pretty clearly how to create custom fields for the user. Look at the code under "Signing up". It shows you an example of how to create a custom phone number field to the user. That's how you do it.